# Potential Problems Caused by Modifying web.config File to Prioritize index.html over index.aspx

Tags: web-config

I am trying to generate and host a flip book catalog on our website using a 3rd party. I downloaded their zip file, unzipped it, and transferred the resulting folder (which includes an index.html file) to our server. However, after trying to open [www.americanmedicals.com/tuff](http://www.americanmedicals.com/tuff), I get a Forbidden: You do not have permission to access this document. I then tried opening [www.americanmedicals.com/tuff/index.html](http://www.americanmedicals.com/tuff/index.html). I get a server error after being automatically redirected to https://www.americanmedicals.com/tuuf/index.aspx. The 3rd party suggests modifying our web.config file from

```
  <files>
    <clear />
<add value="index.aspx" />
  </files>
```

to

```
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="index.html" />
<add value="index.aspx" />
  </files>
```

Our site's home page is index.aspx. Will doing their suggested fix negatively our website in any way? For example, will it cause our site to load more slowly since it would be looking for an index.html file first?

I followed their initial instructions on how to upload and post a catalog to our website. I expected that opening https://www.americanmedicals.com/tuuf/index.html would lead to the catalog. I have not yet tried their suggested fix for fear of hurting our web site in some way.